# Is there a recent version of Apache Derby that is supported in OSGi?

Tags: osgi, derby

I am using Derby 10.8.2 which requires Gemini DBAcess.  These versions are very old (circa 2011) and do not work with JRE > 1.8.

As the title asks, does anyone know of a more recent version that will work in an OSGi evnironment?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Derby community have an open Enhancement Request to support OSGi on the most recent versions of Derby: [DERBY-7056](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-7056)

There are a set of proposed changes to provide this support.

My understanding is that the primary blocker on this is access to somebody who is relatively familiar with OSGi and could test the support, as none of the Derby committers are users of OSGi.

So perhaps you could volunteer to work with the Derby community and help get the OSGi support tested and committed?